# How to create pydantic generic type for checking min_length and max_length on the validate?

Tags: python, generics, types, python-typing, pydantic

I have an idea. In my personal project, I have many methods for checking the described model (checking the password length, username characters, etc.), but what if I describe one Generic class that will work on the principle of specifying certain parameters in it?

Eg:

```py
class User(BaseModel):
     username: String[15,32]
     password: SecretBytes[6,100]
```

Another use case:
I often work with different bases of int and instead of processing values, I would like to be able to specify the type `Int[16]` or `Int[10]`, thanks to which pydantic itself will convert the values ​​to the ones I need if possible

Do you have any ideas how this can be done?

I found an example in the official documentation, but I do not understand how it can be upgraded to my desires.

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, Sequence, TypeVar

from pydantic_core import ValidationError, core_schema
from typing_extensions import get_args

from pydantic import BaseModel

T = TypeVar('T')


class MySequence(Sequence[T]):
    def __init__(self, v: Sequence[T]):
        self.v = v

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.v[i]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.v)

    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(
        cls, source: Any, handler: Callable[[Any], core_schema.CoreSchema]
    ) -> core_schema.CoreSchema:
        instance_schema = core_schema.is_instance_schema(cls)

        args = get_args(source)
        if args:
            # replace the type and rely on Pydantic to generate the right schema
            # for `Sequence`
            sequence_t_schema = handler.generate_schema(Sequence[args[0]])
        else:
            sequence_t_schema = handler.generate_schema(Sequence)

        non_instance_schema = core_schema.general_after_validator_function(
            lambda v, i: MySequence(v), sequence_t_schema
        )
        return core_schema.union_schema([instance_schema, non_instance_schema])


class M(BaseModel):
    model_config = dict(validate_default=True)

    s1: MySequence = [3]


m = M()
print(m)
#> s1=<__main__.MySequence object at 0x0123456789ab>
print(m.s1.v)
#> [3]


class M(BaseModel):
    s1: MySequence[int]


M(s1=[1])
try:
    M(s1=['a'])
except ValidationError as exc:
    print(exc)
    """
    2 validation errors for M
    s1.is-instance[MySequence]
      Input should be an instance of MySequence [type=is_instance_of, input_value=['a'], input_type=list]
    s1.function-after[<lambda>(), json-or-python[json=list[int],python=chain[is-instance[Sequence],function-wrap[sequence_validator()]]]].0
      Input should be a valid integer, unable to parse string as an integer [type=int_parsing, input_value='a', input_type=str]
    """
```

code from: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/custom/#generic-containers

Comment: I understand what you mean to achieve, but you have to know that your examples do not really qualify as _generic_ types. A generic class is always generic _in terms of_ the type of some of its attributes. That is what the Python subscript syntax `[]` for classes expresses -- setting the type argument of a generic class. When you do `String[15, 32]` you are not specifying type arguments, but passing _values_. What you want is for that to return a subclass of `String` with certain restrictions, not a parameterized generic because nothing about the types _inside_ `String` would change.

Comment: While you can certainly construct something like this using `__class_getitem__`, this would probably not be recognized by any standard type checker as a valid annotation. In other words: Yes, you can make this work at runtime, but it would not pass any type checks, unless you were to contort yourself into using `Literal` types, but this would make the syntax really ugly IMO.